# Why does my dishwasher fill when the machine is off?

Tags: plumbing, dishwasher

Water slowly fills my dishwasher cabinet when the machine is off, and eventually leaks out thru door.  Any suggestions on cause and repair video? I have a Whirlpool dishwasher model DU8750XY-0.

Answer (score 4):

Shutoff the water supply to the dishwasher and run water through the sink drain from the faucet.

If the flow of water stops to the dishwasher, then the problem is in the supply and Ed's advice is likely on track. If you find water filling the dishwasher with the supply turned off, then the problem is with the drain line. The drain needs to be attached to the underside of the counter or connected through an air gap at the sink to minimize the risk of water from the drain backing up and into the dishwasher.

Comment: I had never had this problem but it makes sense to me +

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same thing happen in the past. The fill valve on the back side of the unit where the water enters had a small chunk of scale / rust stuck in it. I was able to clean it out and it worked fine for a long time after that. (if there is no filter / screen on the hose fitting you will probably want to add one so once you get it working it wont happen again. If the valve seat is damaged from something being lodged in it the valve may have to be replaced, easy to do once the washer is out and not very expensive. Here is 1 model 38$ [valve for whirlpool](https://www.zoro.com/whirlpool-inlet-valve-w10327249/i/G3380800/?gclid=COrtjYGd1cwCFRSPfgodQkwNgQ&gclsrc=aw.ds).